# How to call method via hyperlink?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I call a method with a hyperlink on my index.html.erb?

I currently have a search field that allows the user to type in a keyword.  This will search attributes in a model and display any that are found.

For example, I have records_controller.rb with this in it:

```
def index
  @records = Record.search(params[:search])
end
```

app/models/record.rb has:

```
  # Added for the search 
  def self.search(search)
    where("title LIKE ? OR keyword LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  end
```

'title, 'keyword', and 'decscription' are attributes in the model.

app/views/records/index.html.erb contains a search form:

```
<%= form_tag(records_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: " Search" %>
<%= submit_tag "Find" %>
<% end %>
```

On this same index.html.erb page, how can I add a hyperlink that displays all data from a model that contains a title I specify?

Such as displaying all rows that have the title "truck".
If the user clicks the hyperlink, it will display data

```
where('title LIKE "truck"', "%#{search}%")
```

I'm assuming I'll also need to put a new method in the record model such as:

```
# I'll have to play with this because I know it is wrong
# Added for the search 
def self.searchtruck(search)
  where('title LIKE "truck"', "%#{search}%")
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by `where('title LIKE "truck"', "%#{search}%")` ? You are not using the search term. Did you mean `where('title LIKE %#{search}%')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you're asking, creates a link with the `param[:search] = 'truck'`

```
<%= link_to 'Search for truck', records_path(search: 'truck') %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that ended up being easier than I thought it would be.  I just had to change "record_path" to "records_path".